# Is struts1's formbean threadsafe or not?

Tags: java, struts1, struts-1

As the title says, is struts1's forbean threadsafe or not?
I saw the code of class ActionServlet, its follow looks like this:
At first, it look up the existing form bean from request or session by the specified "scope", if it exists, then return it, else if it doesn't exist, create new one and return it.
Does it mean if the value of "scope" is request, it will create new instance per request,if the value of "scope" is session, it will use the existed instance?
So the situation of the value of "scope" is request is thread safe, the other situation is not thread safe?
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you mean with "thread safe"? I think it is misleading to think of threads in that web scope. The forms are thread safe in both cases, request and session scope as you will receive 'your' form in the right place and scope when struts is configured correctly.